# How to show most used item in first place in RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have made the application of different tools which have more than 60 tools I want that the user most used item showed in first place in RecyclerView. Please help me how can I do this thing.

[image]

Comment: May be keep a count of how many times user click on an icon and before showing the list of icons, sort them based on this count

Comment: Basically you need to sort the data in the adapter into the order you wish it to display in.  The adapter determines the order of items.

Comment: I was thinking of these solutions but I think this is not a good approach

Comment: in the future, if items increases it will take time to sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a count value for the number of times the user starts the tool from the app. Now you will have a Map with the name of the tool and the count for the number of times it is used. You can use this map to define the order of the list.

Comment: I was thinking of this solutions but I think this is not a good approach in the future if items increase it will take time to sort

Comment: Agreed the complexity of this approach can be a bit higher than the usual list/array option. But surely you won't have 1000s of items. You won't feel the difference in the time taken for the operation. Also, this approach will give you the true most used apps. If you go with a list/set approach, you will move recently used apps to the top or increase them incrementally but this won't give you the truly most used app at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing if possible, like when users click on a particular item in `RecuclerView` then if any API is called on the backend side then from the backend side they can manage hit count(mean how much time particular API calls) at their end and returns count to the frontend on RecyclerView list data. Using that count we can sort the list. This is an approach that I think.